# Windows Form Crash

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, connection-string, unhandled-exception

I am not sure where have i done the mistake.

I created Windows form in which some controls like combo box populates from the Access Database (accdb).
When i create the exe file and install in development PC it works fine but when I install it on different pc, windows throws following error. Looks like it is not able to connect to the database but i am not sure though.

Here is the windows unhandled exception error.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MozillaProfiler.MozillaProfiler.getProfiles()
   at MozillaProfiler.MozillaProfiler.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
MozillaProfiler
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Smart%20Business%20Telecom/Mozilla%20Profiler/MozillaProfiler.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.DirectoryServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.DirectoryServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.DirectoryServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

[image]

What is the actual problem. Do i need to install Microsoft Access Database Engine in the pc where i am installing the application or there is some other alternative to this.

Button2 Event Handler Code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox2.SelectedItem != null)
            {

                button4.Visible = true;
                button5.Visible = true;
                label9.Visible = true;
                comboBox3.Visible = true;
                label14.Visible = false;
                progressBar1.Visible = false;

                DataSet ds = getProfiles();
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    comboBox3.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "identifier";

                }

                // CaluculateAll(progressBar1);
                string[] str = comboBox2.Text.Split(' ');
                string username = str[2].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");

                string server1Path = @"\\192.168.1.32\C$\Users\" + username;
                string server3Path = @"\\192.168.1.40\C$\Users\" + username;
                string server2Path = @"\\192.168.1.33\C$\Users\" + username;
                string server4Path = @"\\192.168.1.34\C$\Users\" + username;

                string server1Mozilla = @"\\192.168.1.32\C$\Users\" + username + @"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla";
                string server3Mozilla = @"\\192.168.1.40\C$\Users\" + username + @"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla";
                string server2Mozilla = @"\\192.168.1.33\C$\Users\" + username + @"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla";
                string server4Mozilla = @"\\192.168.1.34\C$\Users\" + username + @"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla";



                if (Directory.Exists(server1Path)) { pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red; }
                if (Directory.Exists(server2Path)) { pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Red; }
                if (Directory.Exists(server3Path)) { pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.Red; }
                if (Directory.Exists(server4Path)) { pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Red; }
                if (Directory.Exists(server1Mozilla)) { pictureBox5.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox5.BackColor = Color.Red; }
                if (Directory.Exists(server2Mozilla)) { pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.Red; }
                if (Directory.Exists(server3Mozilla)) { pictureBox7.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox7.BackColor = Color.Red; }
                if (Directory.Exists(server4Mozilla)) { pictureBox8.BackColor = Color.Green; } else { pictureBox8.BackColor = Color.Red; }

                if (pictureBox1.BackColor == Color.Green) { server1Profile.Enabled = false; server1Check.Enabled = true; } else { server1Profile.Enabled = true; server1Check.Enabled = false; }
                if (pictureBox2.BackColor == Color.Green) { server2Profile.Enabled = false; server2Check.Enabled = true; } else { server2Profile.Enabled = true; server2Check.Enabled = false; }
                if (pictureBox3.BackColor == Color.Green) { server3Profile.Enabled = false; server3Check.Enabled = true; } else { server3Profile.Enabled = true; server3Check.Enabled = false; }
                if (pictureBox4.BackColor == Color.Green) { server4Profile.Enabled = false; server4Check.Enabled = true; } else { server4Profile.Enabled = true; server4Check.Enabled = false; }

                if ((server1Profile.Enabled == false) && (server2Profile.Enabled == false) && (server3Profile.Enabled == false) && (server4Profile.Enabled == false)) { button4.Visible = false; }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No user selected");
            }

        }


 public DataSet getProfiles()
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnector"].ToString();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT [identifier] FROM [MozillaData]";
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "MozillaData");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database Error");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables["MozillaData"].Rows.Count <= 0)
                return null;

            return dataSet;
        }
```

Comment: What is the code in button2_Click? Can you share it or part of it?

Comment: @Harsh, Please check above

Comment: To answer your question, Yes you can run your application without MS access installed.

Comment: Use try catch block to find out which object is null.

Comment: I know the null is the combo box which is it trying to populate. It works perfectly on development PC when i install on it. It just on other PCs it not working. Also Database file location is also can be seen by all the PCs.

Comment: I am sure it is something to do with the access database connectivity, not sure how do i solve it

Comment: From the error details it seems your application is crashing in getProfiles() function. Can you share the code. If not, check in there which object is returning null.

Comment: When i debug the code it returning the value as expected. I will update the code above for get profiles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65290/discussion-between-harsh-and-amrit-sharma).